# Is it possible to enable CORS on the RSS feed?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, rss

I'd like users to be able to search Stack Overflow Jobs from my site using the RSS feed as an API so I can put the jobs in a different format, but CORS does not appear to be enabled.

I could use my server as a proxy, but it seems like an unnecessary step. Can we get this enabled?

Comment: would this be against the terms of service?

Comment: @DanielA.White, very good question. I read through the [terms of service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public) as well as the [API terms of use](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/api-terms-of-use). I'm not a lawyer, but I _think_ as long as I provide proper attribution as well as links back to the original content (which I do) then I should be okay, but if anyone knows better than me then **please** speak up so I don't waste a bunch of time on something that is not allowed.

Comment: @adam0101 You are correct. We're ok with you hosting our jobs on your site as long as they are attributed back to us and the application link directs them to the job on our site. We also reserve the right to ask you to take down specific jobs at our request. Some customer don't like having their job in an unapproved place.

Comment: I am running into this problem too. I'm trying to embed the feed from tags related to my project into the project's website. I did this in the past with our askbot instance and it was very helpful to give more visibility to the questions. However the rss feeds have CORS disabled so the recent questions cannot be shared with our users . For example https://index.ros.org/p/rclcpp/#rolling-questions  tries to load https://robotics.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag/rclcpp but get blocked by CORS policy `strict-origin-when-cross-origin`